# Deleting the TrustedInstaller user?

Tags: windows-10, security, user-accounts

I'd like to remove the TrustedInstaller authority from my windows 10 system. This is an interesting task, as it seems that TrustedInstaller is simultaneously a user, a service, and a permissions group on windows. It also seems that windows defaults to running some processes as the TrustedInstaller agent. I'd like to replace those agents with an administrator account of my choosing.

The goal is to have my system run as bare-bones as possible when it comes to the security model. I don't want any sort of protection of files, processes, or other resources. Removing the TrustedInstaller user is a significant goal in this regard.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but if you care about these things, why are you using Windows? Linux is free. And if you need to; have you tried Tiny10?

Comment: @Gantendo I do run linux, too! Some things are meant to be windows-only, sadly. So It's really something I'm putting up with

Answer (score 5):

Trustedinstaller is used by Windows and Windows Apps to install software.

It seems to me unrealistic to remove it. I actually do not think you can remove it without breaking Windows.

Windows Updates for Standard User uses this (among other uses).

Comment: I do not need windows updates. It is fine if this functionality is broken, halted, or removed.

Comment: Windows updates install themselves in a lot of cases, whether you think they are needed or not

Comment: I know, I'm saying that if windows updates are the blocker here, this is not an issue.